# Is there a way to implement a many-to-one relationship in DB2?

Tags: db2

I need to create a data structure like this:

```
Table 1
Code, Value, Offer_ID
```

I am creating a service that, for a given combination of "Code" and "Value", must return an Offer_ID that I preconfigured.

For example:

```
Code    Value  Offer_ID
------ ------- ----------
Age       30     OFF1
Age       30     OFF2
Province  RM     OFF2
Age       40     OFF3
Province  TO     OFF3
Age       40     OFF4
Province  TO     OFF4
Operator  TIM    OFF4
```

The calling service always calls me passing the Age, Province and operator values.
I have to look in this table if I find a specific Offer_ID for the three values ​​together (as OFF4), or for 2 (as OFF3) or for Age which is the only mandatory (OFF1).

So if the client passes me Province BO and operator WIND I have to return OFF1

How can I do ? How can I structure the tables and the query?

I hope I was able to expose the problem ...

Thanks 1000 to those who help me ... we are going crazy ... !!!

Comment: What should be returned on the following data: `(age, province, operator, offet_id): (30, RM, TIM, OFF1), (30, TO, TOM, OFF2)` and the user input: `(30, RM, TOM)`?

Comment: The user input can be: "(30, RM, TIM)" and the returned data must be "OFF4".
If the user input is `(30, RM, VODAFONE) 'returned data must be" OFF2 "because there is no combination of the three inputs that identifies an" Offer_ID "identified by the three elements and I return" Offer_ID "identified with only two elements (in this case "Age = 30" and "Province = RM").
If I don't find any "Offer_ID" even with two inputs I have to return "OFF1" which is identified only by the "Age" parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with tab (age, province, operator, offer_id) as (values
  (30, null,  null, 'OFF1')
, (30, 'RM',  null, 'OFF2')
, (40, 'TO',  null, 'OFF3')
, (40, 'TO', 'TIM', 'OFF4')
)
, op_inp (age, province, operator) as (values
--(40, 'TO', 'TIM') --'OFF4'
(40, 'TO', 'VODAFONE') --'OFF3'
--(30, 'RM', 'VODAFONE') --'OFF2'
--(30, 'TO', 'VODAFONE') --'OFF1'
)
select offer_id /*Just for info*/, order_flag
from 
(
select t.*, 3 as order_flag
from tab t
join op_inp o on o.age=t.age and o.province=t.province and o.operator=t.operator
  union all
select t.*, 2 as order_flag
from tab t
join op_inp o on o.age=t.age and o.province=t.province --and t.operator is null
  union all
select t.*, 1 as order_flag
from tab t
join op_inp o on o.age=t.age --and t.province is null and t.operator is null
)
order by order_flag desc
fetch first 1 row only
;
```

Comment: And the question is: what must be returned on the sample data for user input: `(40, 'TO', 'VODAFONE')`? `OFF3` or `OFF4`?

Comment: I add (and I apologize for not being precise) that I could have a request     "(35, null, TIM, OFF5)" and     "(null, BO, VODAFONE, OFF6)". Thank you